# Bootstrap - do we have to use rows and columns?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Let me explain with 2 examples:

```
<div class="row">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <div class="col-md-12">Content</div>
</div>
```

vs

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12"><h1>Title</h1></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">Content</div>
</div>
```

The examples are overly simplified but my question is that does everything have to be within a column or where needed, can they sit outside? Another example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <img src="img/Police2-600x250.jpg" class="full-width">
      <div class="col-md-12 news">
        <p class="date">POSTED <strong>01 APRIL</strong></p>
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <p>This is a summary of what the story is about like a subheading to catch your attention. Blah blah blah b l a h blah blah.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <img src="img/Police2-600x250.jpg" class="full-width">
        <div class="col-md-12 news">
          <p class="date">POSTED <strong>01 APRIL</strong></p>
          <h3>Heading</h3>
          <p>This is a summary of what the story is about like a subheading to catch your attention. Blah blah blah b l a h blah blah.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't want the images to be subject to any padding but I do want the content below it to

Comment: If you try your simple example you see the difference. The first Title has not the same margin as the content. So it's matter if you use a column or not

Comment: Minus votes are making SO an awful place to be. @DestinatioN thank you for commenting. I mean from a strictly code based view rather than asthetics. Apologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They *can* sit outside of a column, but in doing this you're sacrificing padding. Bootstrap's `.row` style sets `margin-left` and `margin-right` to -15px; the `.col-...` classes make up for this with 15px padding on either side.

To make up for it, you'd have to manually add this 15px padding to your non-`.col-...` elements.

That said, however, there's no reason your `h1` can't be a `.col-...` itself:

```
<div class="row">
  <h1 class="col-md-12">Title</h1>
  <div class="col-md-12">Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Let's take aesthetics outside of it - purely from a structure point of view, is it best to contain everything within a column?

Comment: @pee2pee there's no reason you'd have to. They are designed to work together, though. I've updated my answer to include something else.

Comment: Thanks :-) one last question, is it reasonable to have nested columns without a row?

Comment: @pee2pee nested columns will result in additional padding. As mentioned above, a `.row` takes away margin and a `.col-...`  makes up for it with padding. If we class both of these as *position*, we can say that a standalone `.row` gives a position of -15; a `.row ` with a `.col-...` inside gives a position of 0; a `.row` with a `.col-...` with a nested `.col-...` will give a position of 15 (as there's no `.row` to take it away).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Bootstrap's grid, **yes**, the columns must be the direct children of the row, and content should be placed in columns. From the Bootstrap docs...

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro

> Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be
>   immediate children of rows.

Comment: So columns can be children of columns then

Comment: Yes, as long as they're in another `row` tag.. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting

Comment: I then get padding that I don't want though

Comment: Yeah, not sure exactly what you want to acheive, but that's the recommended approach for Bootstrap. Otherwise the padding does this: http://www.codeply.com/go/rrUEmqTvCh